# Conflict of node names when a tikz picture contains other tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have built `tikz` pictures for a large number of small diagrams and given them macro names.  I want to be able to build more complicated pictures which use the defined structures.  However, the names of nodes in the individual small pictures conflict with node names in the bigger pictures.  Here is a contrived example

```
\def\LL{\begin{tikzpicture}\node (n0) at (0,0) {0}; \node (n1) at (-1,1) {L};\draw(n0) to (n1); \end{tikzpicture}}
\def\RR{\begin{tikzpicture}\node (n0) at (0,0) {0}; \node (n1) at (1,1) {R};\draw(n0) to (n1); \end{tikzpicture}}



\begin{tikzpicture} \node (n0) at (0,0)  {\LL};  \node (n1) at (5,0) {\RR};
\draw (n0) to (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives an image in which the final `\draw (n0) to (n1);` uses incorrect node coordinates.
I get what I need by leaving the `\def\LL` and `\def\RR` unchanged but altering the names of the nodes in the outer picture so that this becomes

```
\begin{tikzpicture} \node (m0) at (0,0)  {\LL};  \node (m1) at (5,0) {\RR};
\draw (m0) to (m1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Everything would be fine if the `tikzpicture` acted like a pure procedure without side effects.

Comment: Welcome! Don't include a `tikzpicture` in another one. Regardless of node names. This isn't supported. Occasionally it works in simple cases, but it will, basically break. Note that you can format code by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: Please post code we can (try to) compile as is by providing a preamble and `document` environment.

Answer (score 8):

Nesting `tikzpicture`s is not supported. Period.

If it works, you have either struck lucky or unlucky, according to your desperation and perspective. Unlucky because if it works, you may continue to use the method and  you may think your existing code should continue to work. That is, probably you will have more pain in the end, though less pain now. Lucky, if you really need it to work this moment and don't care whether it works next week.

This is regardless of naming conflicts etc. It isn't supported at all.

You probably have 2 options, depending on the details.

First, make each macro with a small picture use a box. From what you've said, I recommend this method strongly. It will be both easy and faster compile-time wise.

```
\newsavebox\LLbox
\sbox\LLbox{\begin{tikzpicture}\node (n0) at (0,0) {0}; \node (n1) at (-1,1) {L};\draw(n0) to (n1); \end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand*\LL{\usebox{\LLbox}}
```

Second, use `pic`s. I would use this only if you need more flexibility than your MWE suggests. Otherwise, it involves unnecessary faff and will be unnecessarily slow for no benefit at all.

```
\tikzset{%
  LL/.pic={
    \node (n0) at (0,0) {0};
    \node (n1) at (-1,1) {L};
    \draw (n0) to (n1);
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {LL};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which I think would work. If you'd posted usable code, I'd test it. But you didn't, so I can't without completing it first which I don't have time for right now.

You can work around the fact that a `pic` is not a `node`, so that you have a named thing to connect to, if that's important. However, don't use the method in the manual as `pic`s are currently very buggy and naming has been broken for a while. (It used to work, so maybe it will again, but it doesn't now.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of macros, use saveboxes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}\node (n0) at (0,0) {0}; \node (n1) at (-1,1) {L};\draw(n0) to (n1); \end{tikzpicture}}
\sbox1{\begin{tikzpicture}\node (n0) at (0,0) {0}; \node (n1) at (1,1) {R};\draw(n0) to (n1); \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{tikzpicture} \node (n0) at (0,0)  {\usebox0};  \node (n1) at (5,0) {\usebox1};
\draw (n0) to (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't the LaTeX syntax a bit safer? I'd always thought it must be, but then I've never really done it any other way, so I don't know. I just learnt the LaTeX syntax and used that ....

Comment: Using a named savebox (\newsavebox) is safer than a box number.  I just didn't want to go to the effort.

Comment: So that's why you got your answer typed before me!

Answer (score 1):

As cfr already mentioned, it's better that you use `pics` if you want to compose a complex `tikzpicture` with more simpler ones.

Your commands can be converted into `pics`. `Pics` can have a name which prepends the nodes inside them. Following example show how two pics which contains nodes `-right` and `-left` can be used inside the complex figure without presenting conflicts with node's names:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    circles/.pic={%
        \node[circle, draw, minimum size=1cm, fill] (-right) at (1,0) {-right};
        \node[circle, draw, minimum size=1cm, fill] (-left) at (-1,0) {-left};
        \draw (-right)--(-left);
    },
    boxes/.pic={%
        \node[draw, minimum size=1cm, fill] (-right) at (1,0) {-right};
        \node[draw, minimum size=1cm, fill] (-left) at (-1,0) {-left};
        \draw (-right)--(-left);
    }]

\draw[fill=white, red, fill=orange] pic (A) at (0,0) {circles};

\draw[line width=2pt, red, fill=orange] pic (B) at (0,1.5) {boxes};

\draw[red] (B-left) to[out=60,in=120] (B-right);
\draw[blue] (A-left) to[out=60,in=-120] (B-right);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Using `name prefix`

Another option which avoids using `pics` is `name prefix`.

> The value of this key is prefixed to every node inside the current
>   scope. This includes both the naming of the node (via the name key or
>   via the implicit (hnamei) syntax) as well as any referencing of the
>   node. Outside the scope, the nodes can (and need to) be referenced
>   using “full name” consisting of the prefix and the node name.

You can convert your macros from `tikzpictures` to `scopes`. A `name prefix` passed as parameter to the corresponding scope will add the prefix to node's names and all nodes will have different name.

This solution applied to your example could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\LL}[1]{%
\begin{scope}[#1]
\node (n0) at (0,0) {0}; \node (n1) at (-1,1) {L}; \draw(n0) to (n1);
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\RR}[1]{%
\begin{scope}[#1]
\node (n0) at (0,0) {0}; \node (n1) at (1,1) {L}; \draw(n0) to (n1);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \LL{name prefix=First-}

 \RR{shift={(5,0)}, name prefix=Second-}

 \draw (First-n0) to (Second-n1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative to `pics` based on `name prefix` option.